# SQL Query - top 1 in join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I would like to combine tables User with Firma

table dbo.User

```
Id  Server  Database    BiEnable    BiPerm
1   5       TEST        1           NULL
```

table dbo.Firma

```
FId FKod    FAktywna    FInst
1   TEST    0           3
2   TEST    0           4
4   TEST    1           5
```

Linking must take place via the [Database] field in the [User] table with the [Fkod] field in the [Firma] table, but only with the line where [Fid] is always the largest (case we have some of the same names).
How should this query look like?

@edit:
expected result:

```
Id  Server  Database    BiEnable    BiPerm  FId FKod    FAktywna    FInst
1   5       TEST        1           NULL    4   TEST    1           5
```

Comment: Pls add expected result

Comment: `join Firma f on f.Fid = max(f.Fid)` ?

Comment: There is possible that FId  have multiple equally  largest values for same FKod    ?

Comment: What is your sql-server version? Modern versions have handy windowing functions/

Comment: @SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the highest `FId` for each `FKod`

```
select  FKod, max(FId)
from    Firma
group by FKod
```

Then you can use that as a filter by joining it with the two original tables

```
select  *
from    User t1
join    Firma t2
on      t1.Database = t2.FKod
join    (
            select  FKod, max(FId) FId
            from    Firma
            group by FKod
        ) t3
on      t2.FId = t3.FId and
        t2.FKod = t3.FKod
```

Comment: Glad it helped! If this **or any other answer** has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this (I think it would be a good habit to avoid, if possibile, to use name like USER and DATABASE or other reserved MSSQL words in your tables):

```
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM [USER] A
INNER JOIN FIRMA B ON A.[DATABASE] = B.FKOD
INNER JOIN (SELECT FKOD, MAX(FID) AS MAXFID FROM FIRMA GROUP BY FKOD) C ON A.[DATABASE] = C.FKOD AND C.MAXFID =B.FID
```

If you can use windows analytical functions:

```
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM [USER] A
INNER JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FKOD ORDER BY FID DESC) AS RN FROM FIRMA) B ON A.DATABASE = B.FKOD AND B.RN = 1
```

Comment: I think in the first option you should join on both `A.DATABASE = C.FKOD` and `B.FID = C.MAXFID`, otherwise the inner query that returns the `max` is useless

Comment: Yes, i missed a part for copy / paste.  Now I edit the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the same idea as in the  @etsa's query, simplified using WITH TIES

```
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM [USER] A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES * 
    FROM FIRMA
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FKOD ORDER BY FID DESC)
) B ON A.DATABASE = B.FKOD
```